# Is there a way that can I extract the values from this output summary?

Tags: r, statistics, summary

How can I extract the values of (**'Estimate'**, **'std. Error'**, **'Pr (> | z |)'**) from the output results and place them in a table format from the data example below?

```
require(GJRM)
set.seed(123)
x1 <- sample(1:100, size = 20)
bid1 <- sample(c(5, 10, 20, 30), size = 20, replace = T)
bid2 <- sample(c(5, 10, 20, 30), size = 20, replace = T)
ans1 <- sample(c(1,0), size = 20, replace = T)
ans2 <- sample(c(1,0), size = 20, replace = T)
df <- cbind(x1, bid1, bid2, ans1, ans2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
treat.eq <- ans1 ~ bid1 + x1
out.eq <- ans2 ~ bid2 + x1
f.list <- list(treat.eq, out.eq)
mr <- c("probit", "probit")
## Model
bvp <- gjrm(f.list, data=df, Model="B", margins= mr)
summary(bvp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is present in `model$tableP1` and `model$tableP2` :

```
library(GJRM)
bvp <- gjrm(f.list, data=df, Model="B", margins= mr)
model <- summary(bvp)
model$tableP1

#               Estimate Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept)  0.83797602 0.79822170  1.049804 0.2938084
#bid1        -0.04682910 0.03137645 -1.492492 0.1355702
#x1          -0.01065357 0.00993613 -1.072205 0.2836278

model$tableP2

#                Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept)  0.434060433 0.64213719  0.6759621 0.4990647
#bid2        -0.012464492 0.02930301 -0.4253656 0.6705702
#x1          -0.005763137 0.01025844 -0.5617947 0.5742559
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you !

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that because my reputation score is not enough. My score is less than 15

Comment: Wow! Sorry for that. I did it now. Is it ok now? Thanks